# PDF Signing with ExternalSiging service using iText,

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I have a pdf Document and that need to be digitally signed and the signature is provided by external service. I don't have the certificate chain prior to initiate the signature. I tried the following code but getting SigDict/Contents illegal data message.

source to create document hash and post that to external service to sign it

```
    InputStream data = null;
    DocumentSignStatus documentSignStatus = new DocumentSignStatus();
    int contentEstimated = 8192;

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(requestParams.getDocumentToBeSigned());
    try {
    reader.unethicalreading = true;

    int pdfPagenumber = 1;

    if((Integer)requestParams.getSignPageNo() == null || requestParams.getSignPageNo()==0  ){           
        //pdfPagenumber = 1; // Default signature on first page.
        pdfPagenumber = reader.getNumberOfPages(); // Sign on last page

    }else {
        pdfPagenumber = requestParams.getSignPageNo();
    }

    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream  os = null;

    os = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();        
    appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();        
    appearance.setSignDate(cal);
    appearance.setAcro6Layers(false);
    appearance.setReason("Test Signature");
    appearance.setLocation("India");               
    appearance.setImage(null);
    appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);

    Rectangle rect = requestParams.getRect();        
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(rect, pdfPagenumber, null);

    HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();
    exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new Integer(contentEstimated * 2 + 2));
    PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    dic.setReason(appearance.getReason()); 
    dic.setLocation(appearance.getLocation());
    dic.setContact(appearance.getContact());
    dic.setDate(new PdfDate(appearance.getSignDate()));
    appearance.setCryptoDictionary(dic);

    appearance.preClose(exc);

    data = appearance.getRangeStream();    

    MessageDigest messageDigest;
    String provider = null;
    String hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;
    if (provider == null){
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm);
    }else {
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm,provider);
    }


    int read = 0;
    byte[] buff = new byte[contentEstimated];

    while ((read = data.read(buff, 0, contentEstimated)) > 0)
    {
        messageDigest.update(buff,0,read);                      
    }
    byte[] hashDigest = messageDigest.digest();

    byte[] documentHash = org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.encode(hashDigest);

    //eSign Start        
    String hashdocument = new String(documentHash, "UTF-8");        
    System.out.println("Document Hash :"+hashdocument);


    //Generate Sign Request XML for external source to sign the document hash                
    String eSignXmlStr = esignXML.generateEsignXML20(hashdocument,requestParams.getAadhaarNo());                
    String eSignSignedXML = myXMLSigner.signXML(eSignXmlStr, true);
    System.out.print("sign request xml: " + eSignSignedXML);
    // sign request xml generation complete


    documentSignStatus.setSignedXML(eSignSignedXML);        
    session.put("hashdocument", documentHash);
    session.put("appearance", appearance);
    session.put("baos", os);

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return documentSignStatus;
```

Following is the source to attach the PKCS7 response to pdf to complete the signature procedure and get the signed pdf.

```
    byte[] hashdocument = (byte[])session.get("hashdocument");
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance =  (PdfSignatureAppearance)session.get("appearance");
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = (ByteArrayOutputStream)session.get("baos");

    //Get signed response xml
    InputStream x = request.getInputStream();
    String responseXML = IOUtils.toString(x, "UTF-8");
    System.out.print("REsponse:" + responseXML);

    //parse the xml and get pkcs7 data
    String pkcs7asString = getPKCS7DataFromDigitalSignatureResponse(responseXML);
    byte[] signedDocByte = org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.decode(pkcs7asString);

    //////////////////// ADD SIGNED BYTES/HASH TO PDF DOCUMENT.                 
    int contentEstimated = 8129;
    byte[] paddedSig = new byte[contentEstimated];                   
    System.arraycopy(signedDocByte, 0, paddedSig, 0, signedDocByte.length);
    PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
    dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true));
    try {
        appearance.close(dic2);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                   
    try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/SignTest2.0.pdf")) {
        os.writeTo(outputStream);
    }

    os.close();
```

The method getPKCS7DataFromDigitalSignatureResponse(responseXML) is used to parse the external service response it returns a PKCS7 as String.
I tried to figure out the problem but couldn't find the root cause.
can anyone help to sort out this issue. Using itext version 5.4.5 copy od signed document is [PDF with Signature Problem](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z3XoVD4kswOYHO7LSflq3Bp0W3euXThY)

Comment: your code looks like you took some ancient signing samples as template. If you're using iText 5 (instead of the more current and actively developed iText 7), at least switch to the newest 5.5.x version available. And then do use the current signing APIs.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the suggestion, found the root cause, I was using wrong value for padding byte array 8219 instead of 8192.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of the issue, I made a small mistake, the content estimation variable in not correct in above source due to that paddedSig  was not created properly.
Wrong value as shown in above source.  `int contentEstimated = 8129;`
Correct Value is  `int contentEstimated = 8192;`
Rest of the code is fine.

Comment: Neither 8129 or 8192 is more correct. But the two estimates in your two pieces of code must be equal, which estimate ever you may use.

Comment: @mkl Ohh I didn't know that, thanks for the info. I saw that value 8192 in itext examples and tried the same. Actually I didn't get properly the use of content estimates can you please put some light on this.

Comment: *"I didn't get properly the use of content estimates can you please put some light on this."* - Depending on the technical and legal context in which a signature is created, certain additional information must become part of the signature container you eventually embed into the PDF. Thus, these signature containers can vary considerably in size. On the other hand a placeholder for that signature container in the PDF must be prepared before signing and the signature container to inject must not be larger. Thus, a sensible estimate of the size is required and cannot be changed after signing.